# Parenthesis Balancing in Scala

Tags: scala

Here is my problem: I don't understand how the code works. 
 How does `"())("` return `false`?

```
def balance(chars: List[Char], numOpens: Int): Boolean = {
  if (chars.isEmpty) {
    numOpens == 0
  } else {
    val h = chars.head
    val n =
      if (h == '(') numOpens + 1
      else if (h == ')') numOpens - 1
      else numOpens
    if (n >= 0) balance(chars.tail, n)
    else false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The lines:

```
if (n >= 0) balance(chars.tail, n)
else false
```

mean that if at any point there are any unbalanced `)` characters, `false` will be returned immediately (n will be < 0). For the specific example you give: `())(` we can follow how the value of n varies as the function works through the string:

- First character - `(`: n -> 1, continue check using remaining characters: `))(`
- Second character - `)`: n -> 0, continue check using remaining characters: `)(`
- Third character - `)`: n -> -1, `else` triggered - return `false` immediately. The fourth character is never checked.

Answer (score 3):

[Shadowlands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322849/shadowlands)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18940994/406435) is correct, but I hope you'll find this more demonstrative:

Let's imagine we are on the top upper stair of infinite stairway. And there is an instruction: `(` means `step down` (`↓`), `)` means `step up` (`↑`) and you should ignore all other instructions.

```
val n =
  if (h == '(') numOpens + 1 // step down
  else if (h == ')') numOpens - 1 // step up
  else numOpens // ignore
```

After the last step we have to stand on the top upper stair. Otherwise instruction is invalid.

```
if (chars.isEmpty) {
  numOpens == 0
} else { ... }
```

You can't make a step up from the top upper stair, otherwise instruction is invalid.

```
if (n >= 0) ...
else false // there is no stairs upper than the upper one (0)
```

Example:

`())(` means `↓↑↑↓`. After this part `↓↑`  you'll be on the top upper stair, so you can't make step up after next command (`↑`) (`n < 0`), so the instruction is invalid.